# How to disable all Windows 10 hot keys in pycharm or intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

Using PyCharm and IntelliJ on Windows and using some hot keys.
But some hot keys are reserved for Windows hot keys.
ex. ctrl + alt + M is for the extract a method to refactor in PyCharm,
but if I hit it, it pops up Manager Notes in Windows 10.

This has been really annoying since some of hot keys I frequently use are reserved for window 10 and needed to change these in key maps in IDE which is time consuming.

Is there a way to disable the windows hot key in these IDEs?

Answer (score 0):

Global hotkeys used by Windows cannot be used in the IDE or in any other app. The app has no way to override them. You should disable them in Windows instead or change the IDE keymap to use different hotkeys. There is no other solution.